# Android sdkmanadger.bat file being deleted (Which Unity relies on)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am building a project using Android SDK.

In Unity Edit > Preferences > External Tools I am pointing the Android SDK Tools to the correct location.
Unity relies on a batch file called sdkmanager

I think mine is being deleted, probably by a Window's 10 update as I have visibly watched it disappear. Is anybody else experiencing this issue? It causes the build to fail. Is there anything I can do to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall the Android module for your Unity version in Unity Hub under

Installs -> Add Module -> Unity Version -> Android Module with tools

This will solve any dependency and configuration issues. Uninstall Android Studio prior if it doesn't give you the option to install the module for your Unity version.

Comment: Unity hub isn't offering the version I need, therefore I needed to install it separately. I was also experiencing similar issues with it.

Comment: What Unity version are you using? I've never heard of that before

Comment: Unity version 2019.3.13f1

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16QXo0QpIOeJfKWm4jBeojxl2TxHy8Fbb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What happens if you try to add modules to it? Android Module is most definitely available for that Unity Version

Comment: Because I installed it outside of the hub, I can link to it within the hub but cannot add modules. I just have 'show in explorer' and 'remove from the hub' options

Comment: Antivirus software was deleting the file. All solved now.... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If files are disappearing, it's most likely an application removing this file. As written in a comment here, so also in my case, it was an Antivirus software.

Ours was so hidden, it didn't even leave an icon in the icon-tray ... but eventually we found it. Since it was quite an unknown software, we replaced it by a better known brand.